# Passing an array inside the "parameters" of adapter in Worklight

Tags: adapter, invoke, ibm-mobilefirst

The code part:

```
function PushRequests(strUser, eClientType, iSectorId, strDeviceId, arrRequests) {

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : 'SomeAddress/PushRequests',
        parameters : {
            'strUser' : strUser.toString(),
            'eClientType' : eClientType.toString(),
            'iSectorId' : iSectorId.toString(),
            'strDeviceId' : strDeviceId.toString(),
            'arrRequests' : arrRequests // <- the array
        }
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

**The response:**
Procedure invocation error. Content is not allowed in prolog.,Failed to parse the payload from backend (procedure: HttpRequest)

I have tried to strignify the array by the navite way and via JSON. This is not the solution.

I know the problem is with the array passed. Does anybody know a workaround, or a way to correctly pass an array to the adapter?

Comment: Did you try passing a string? For example: `var arrRequests = ['[', "'hello'", ']'].join('')` that should return `"['hello']"`.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the problem is with the array passed.

How do you know this?

> Content is not allowed in prolog.

This is almost always a symptom of passing data to an XML parser that is invalid XML, or has some characters before the prolog, which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

In your adapter, you've told it to expect XML from the backend HTTP service you're calling.  I was able to reproduce the same message you see by returning invalid XML from my backend HTTP service.  In fact, I can put anything in the response that is invalid XML, and I'll get the "Content is not allowed in prolog." message.  I can return a page that is a 404 page, or with a Content-Type header of "text/plain".  The adapter was told to expect XML, but given something else.

Please be sure to check that you are not getting a 404 page, or 500, or something else from the backend HTTP service your adapter is calling.

**Here's how I reproduced the "Content is not allowed in prolog" message from my adapter:**

First, create an adapter with xmltester.xml:

```
<wl:adapter name="xmltester"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

<displayName>xmltester</displayName>
<description>xmltester</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>localhost</domain>
        <port>3000</port>   
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getStuff"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

and xmltester-impl.js:

```
function getStuff() {
var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : 'index.xml',
        parameters : {
            'arrRequests' : JSON.stringify(['one', 'two'])
        }
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

I created a [node](http://nodejs.org/) server (server.js) to be my backend:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.get('/index.xml', function(req, res){
  var body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><boo/>';
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
  res.end(body);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port %s', port);
```

Started the server:

```
npm install express
node server.js
```

Then created a Worklight app with a button:

```
<button id="doit">Do it!</button>
```

And linked up a click listener to see what I get back from Worklight when the adapter is invoked:

```
$ = WLJQ;
$("#doit").click(function() {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'xmltester',
        procedure : 'getStuff',
        parameters : []
    };
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess : function(data) {alert("SUCCESS" + JSON.stringify(data));},
        onFailure : function(data) {alert("FAILURE" + JSON.stringify(data));}
    });
    return false;
});
```

I could recreate the problem exactly when my backend server returned a payload with extra characters in front of the prolog (which you can try yourself by editing the server.js code above), like:

```
somethinghere<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Or any non-XML payload, for that matter.

Comment: 1. I know the problem is with the array, because without it the adapter works.
2. The XML is valid. The message "content is not allowed in prolog" appeared to be caused by a mismatch between the server's response type and the expected one because of a wrong request construction.
3. The solution was to use SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
returnedContentType : 'xml'
```

> Failed to parse the payload from backend

Is the returned content in xml format? If not, can you cange the returnedContentType field to 'plain' or 'html' or whichever format you are expecting it in?